# SQL question!. I want to update some part of link from SQL column

Tags: sql

SQL question!
I want to update some part of link (see part of links below) from column "images" into table "wp_time" in my database.
How can I do that

Tnks

(old)
http://localhost/WP_Impres/................
(new)
https://www.riam5.com/.................

Answer (score 0):

depends on your dbms you can use `replace` command :

```
update table
set images = replace(images,'http://localhost/WP_Impres/','https://www.riam5.com/')
```